# Check if one field in object is not empty in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an object which include many fields. example:

House
 - windows
 - doors
 - pipes
etc.

I'm looking for an elegant way to check if one of the element is not null.
instead of - `if (windows != null || doors != null || pipes...)`

Comment: Why do you want to enter the condition only when you have at least one non-null value? What are you doing afterwards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to use reflection, you can build a `List` and use [`any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) on it:

```
val anyElementNull = listOf(window, doors, pipes).any { it != null }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`listOfNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html), e.g.

```
val allNonNullValues = listOfNotNull(windows, doors, pipes)
if (allNonNullValues.isNotEmpty()) { // or .isEmpty() depending on what you require
// or instead just iterate over them, e.g.
allNonNullValues.forEach(::println)
```

If you do not like that, you can also use [`all`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html), [`none`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/none.html) or [`any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) e.g.:

```
if (listOf(windows, doors, pipes).any { it != null }) {
if (!listOf(windows, doors, pipes).all { it == null }) {
if (!listOf(windows, doors, pipes).none { it != null }) {
```

For your current condition the `any`-variant is probably the nicest. `all` and `none` however win if you want to ensure that all or none of the entries match a certain criteria, e.g. `all { it != null }` or `none { it == null }`.

Or if none of the above really fits you, supply your own function instead, e.g.:

```
fun <T> anyNotNull(vararg elements : T) = elements.any { it != null }
```

and call it as follows:

```
if (anyNotNull(windows, doors, pipes)) {
```

Answer (score 4):

You can chain use the [elvis](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) operator which acts as a shorthand for `if(x != null) x else y`:

```
if( null != windows ?: doors ?: pipes )
```

This will go through each field and return the first non-null one, or `null` in case last element in the chain is null.

You should try to avoid allocating entire lists/arrays for such a simple comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filterNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html).

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var myObj = MyObj()
    myObj.house = "house"
    myObj.windows = "windows"
    print(listOf(myObj.house, myObj.windows, myObj.doors).filterNotNull());
    // prints: [house, windows]
}

class MyObj {
    var house: String? = null
    var windows: String? = null
    var doors: Int? = null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

val houseArray= !listOf("window", "doors", "pipes").isNullOrEmpty()

Comment: Please include an explanation when you post code, and also format code with ``` at the start and ``` at the end (the ``` should be on their own lines)